# JMeter Pepper-Box plug-in: how to encrypt messages?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

At the moment I’m able to send messages to my Kafka topic using JMeter’s Pepper-Box load generator plugin.

However these messages are not being accepted as they are unencrypted. I can’t work out whether it’s a JMeter or Pepper-Box parameter I need to change to encrypt the messages. Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to [create a custom function](https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box#custom-functions) for the message payload encryption.

Another thing to consider is switching from PepperBox to [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler), it might be easier

```
def props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
props.put("acks", "all");
props.put("retries", 0);
props.put("batch.size", 16384);
props.put("linger.ms", 1);
props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

def producer = new org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer<>(props);

producer.send(new org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord<>("your-topic", "your-key", "your-encrypted-value"));

producer.close();
```

See [Apache Kafka - How to Load Test with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-kafka-how-to-load-test-with-jmeter) article for more information if needed